# HttpClient декодирует мой Uri

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, есть POST Action, который обрабатывает такой url:

```
api/{id}/{path}
```

На клиенте я формирую строчку, что бы обратиться к Api и выполняю экранирование параметра Path с помощью `Uri.EscapeDataString`.

Шлю запрос, а в логах сервера я вижу, что мой Url не сматчился нигде из-за того, что path был декодирован при отправке...

Такая проблема у меня возникает при использовании .Net Framework 4.0, который нужно использовать в данном проекте. В .Net Core 3.0 такая проблема не воспроизводится...

Что я могу сделать, что бы решить данную проблему?

Comment: поставить `*` тогда в path все что после `/` будет

Comment: @Grundy это на стороне Api сделать нужно? А если Api не мой, то есть решения?

Comment: попробуйте альтернативный HttpMessageHandler

Answer (score 1):

В общем, если заэкранировать `{path}` 2 раза `Uri.EscapeDataString`, то он снимает только один уровень экранирования и остается мой желаемый Uri.

Comment: А при переходе на Net Core снова всё поломается? Это ж костыль, а не решение...

Comment: @PavelMayorov можно и так сказать... Но перехода не ожидается в обозримом будущем, а комментарий на этом месте я оставлю.